# V4L2 Webcam has weird colours in Motion stream, normal on VLC

Tags: raspbian, camera, vlc, motion

I've set up a webcam stream with Motion to use with Octoprint on my Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian 10). With my main webcam (Logitech C270) it works well as expected.

I was testing to see if I could use a quite old webcam (Sunplus Flexcam 100 according to `lsusb`) I just found. I've managed to make it work, through VLC I can see the video feed just fine:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjF0c.png (my red jumper and a green plastic object as color reference)

However, when I start Motion, the image I see on the stream has the colours distorted (kind of looks like green and red are interchanged):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjyNv.png

I've tried changing the `palette` and `hue` config options, but nothing changes. I've also tried using the v4l2 prefix, as in `v4l2:///dev/video0` in the `videodevice` config option, but it does not recognize it as valid.

Any ideas as to what might be happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I know what you're TALKING about, I have one Spinel running off Motion in a Pi4 that's doing it. I have another running off Motion on another Pi4 (system card a CLONE of the other Pi) that has normal color. Thought it was the camera, but swapped it out with one of those bare-board Spinels and the new one STILL has the weird colors. I've got THREE Spinels set up at my office for security on Pi's and NONE of them have the weird colors.

All I changed on the cloned card was the cam name and streaming port. I do use two shell scripts to manually set some v4l2 params (every 15 minutes, and there's a daytime and nighttime script). But even THOSE were cloned from the other card.

Last ditch tonite - Change the USB CABLE. It's the last "original" part.

I do like the Spinel ultra-low-light cams though, can usually see *something* even when, to the eye, it's absolutely black outdoors.